# Где смотреть обновления

Tags: android

Ребят очень хотелось бы Узнать где смотреть  обновления под АНдроид.Что нового вышло что устарело что будет,Короче остававаться на плоту .Благодарю за ответы и ссылки ,Знаю такой вопрос задавать тут нельзя ,но каюсь простите

Comment: Да везде! Хабр, в основном

Comment: Привет а что злимся?)можешь дать ссылку на блог об андроид

Comment: Я не злюсь :) Это было восклицание как возглас

Comment: У нас на so есть пацан с ником tse, так вот у него личный сайт. Отличный кстати. А вообще любой, блогов навалом

Comment: так дай мне любую ссылку )))))))))))))дай я его сайт tse

Comment: [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com) - официальный блог гугл по андроид-разработке. [Android Weekly](http://androidweekly.net/#latest-issue) - еженедельный дайджест. Статьи о разработке, новости, новые библиотеки и тд. [Android digest](http://www.androiddevdigest.com/) - аналогичный ресурс. На всех есть подписка по RSS

Comment: @pavlofff Благодарю!очень полезные ссылки

Comment: Большая подборка ресурсов любого формата: [https://habrahabr.ru/company/avito/blog/334264/](http://habrahabr.ru/company/avito/blog/334264/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую подписаться на рассылку http://apptractor.ru/, они присылают отличные выжимки из мира мобильной разработки каждую неделю.

Вот список последнего письма, со ссылками на соответствующие ресурсы:

**iOS:**
 - Многопоточность (concurrency) в Swift 3. GCD и Dispatch Queues
 - Немного о Swift runtime или куда пропал NSObject
 - 33 iOS библиотеки с открытым исходным кодом, которые будут популярны в 2017 году
 - Оптимизация механики и графики в игре жанра «симулятор» на iOS
 - iOS: Работа с галереей (Photos framework). Часть 2
 - Почему у иконок в iOS такая форма?
 - Apple позволит разработчикам отвечать на отзывы
 - В iOS 10.3 можно будет менять иконку приложения без его обновления
 - Руководство по созданию дополненной реальности в iOS
 - За пределами ограничений: Создаем iOS-анимации при помощи Auto Layout
 - DGNotifyView: анимированные уведомления
 - CRPageViewController: библиотека для листания карточек
 - Fiber2D: кроссплатформенный игровой движок на Swift
 - Files: удобный API для работы с файловой системой

**Android:**
 - Ломаем Android. Как глубока кроличья нора?
 - Ещё немного про телефоны Xiaomi и борьбу с ними
 - Обзор Android Shortcuts
 - Подключаем ККМ АТОЛ к AndroidStudio (обновление к ФЗ-54) 
 - Clean Recycler Adapter. Часть 1
 - В Google Play можно публиковать приложения для Daydream
 - Вышла последняя developer preview версия Android Wear 2.0
 - 20 Open Source проектов для Android, которые могут научить вас новому
 - Google начинает тестирование Instant Apps
 - Делаем сайт на React на Android-устройстве
 - Лучшие практики Push-уведомлений в Android
 - ObjectBox — новая мобильная база данных
 - Выбор элементов RecyclerView перетаскиванием
 - Управление Wi-Fi при помощи WifiManager
 - Фишки для Android-разроаботчиков: градиент
 - Круговая анимация переходов между Фрагментами
 - MVC vs. MVP vs. MVVM на Android
 - Badger: бейджи для drawable
 - PreviewSeekBar: полоска перемотки с превью (как в Google Play Movies)

Также, в письме были темы "Разработка" (18 статей), "Аналитика, маркетинг и монетизация" (4 статьи), "Устройства и IoT" (6 статей)

Мне лично, в работе, эти рассылки очень помогают.

Comment: СПасибо Андрей Большоей!!!!!!!!!!!!!Это то что я Искал.11111111

Answer (score 1):

Как писали выше и плюс к прочему:

[Поиск на habr : Дайджест интересных материалов для мобильного разработчика](https://habrahabr.ru/search/?target_type=posts&q=%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&order_by=date)

[GitHub : wasabeef/awesome-android-libraries](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-libraries)

Еще бывает, просто захожу в Play Market и ищу приложения по ключевым словам: **example**, **android lib**, **lib demo** etc. Тут можно сказать черпаю идеи/вдохновение по Android UI.

P.S. Ссылка на github и совет с поиском в Play Market конечно не гарантирует что получишь актуальные новости, но можешь найти что то строе, но до сих пор актуальное.